# jquery: i'm unable to get either $.get or $('#idOfElement').load to work in even the most simple example.

Tags: jquery, ajax

How embarrassing.  I had this working on a previous project, but now i am unable to get the simplest examples
of load and $.get  to work right.

My simple little web page is shown below.  When i use firebug i can see that http requests are being made
(in the case below to cnn.com, i also tried google.)   But firebug shows these requests in red for some reason.

The div with id 'container' does not get updated. and i never see the callback indicating 'here is the data'.

Must be something real simple and dumb..but after tinkering for an hour i'm ready to cry for help.

any advice much appreciated.   Thanks !

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>

         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

              alert('in ready handler');
              $('#container').load('http://www.cnn.com/');
              alert('after container load');
              $.get(
                    'http://www.cnn.com/', 
                    function(data) {  
                        alert('here is the data' + data); 
                    } 
              );
              alert('after get was called');
            });

          </script>
        </head>

        <body>
        the container:
          <div id="container"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cross domain protection mechanism.

The best option is to have a simple php file on your server which requests the content from the remote site and send it back e.g.

AJAX.php

```
$ echo file_get_contents('http://www.cnn.com/');
```

You JS

```
$ ('#container').load('ajax.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you host your code on `cnn.com` you cannot load resources from another domain using AJAX.

Comment: If you really need to do it, there are some techniques - http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: Thanks, Illia -    I'll call Ted Turner and ask if his tech guys can get me access to upload my crap there ;^)      Or maybe i'll follow the other good advice provided here and just create a simple little web app to test this out, rather than a static HTML file.       Seriously though... THanks a bunch for the help (all of you who responded.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Dales comment:

sometimes file_get_contents from remote server is not allowed (might be allow_url_fopen false on server). so you can use curl instead.

Your JS file

```
 $ ('#container').load('curlRequest.php');
```

Your curlRequest.php file

```
    $ch = curl_init("http://www.cnn.com/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //you can use get method also here
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);      
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was basically provided by Illia and Dale (thanks, gentlemen).

I will add the following to their answer, which was suggested by my friend Eric.

He basically suggested that i check the console !    I should have done this in the first place.  When I enable the console in Chrome I see the following error when I hit my page:

```
 2XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.cnn.com/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Had I seen that when i was first playing with this problem that would have tipped me off.

The only problem is I see that error when i enable the console in Chrome, but i don't see it when i use Firebug in Firefox.  So I guess the moral of the story for me is to try my request in Chrome if Firebug is not giving me sufficient info.  [ Until i figure out how to get this info from Firebug, which I will post when i do.]